# K3b not now working in Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: 16.04, k3b

I have been using k3b for years on Ubuntu: I really, really like it. It's one of my favourite applications.
Today I tried to use it. First, the icon had disappeared from my launcher. When I searched using the HUD it was not found. I went to Ubuntu Software and tried to install it and the installation will not complete: the progress bar just stops and then goes back to the "Install" position.
I think the recent updates to the kernel must have messed things up. I went to the terminal to try to install it: this was the output:

```
$ sudo apt-get install k3b
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
k3b : Depends: kde-runtime (> 4:4.10) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libk3b6 (= 2.0.3-0ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libkde3support4 (>= 4:4.4.4) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libqt4-qt3support (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libk3b6-extracodecs but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to "purge" K3b in the terminal but the message displayed was:
"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'k3b' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libllvm3.8 libllvm3.8:i386 linux-hwe-edge-tools-4.10.0-26
linux-tools-4.10.0-26-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them."

Can anyone tell me how I can reinstall my beloved k3B? If you know what I need to do please keep it simple: I am not a Linux expert.

Comment: First clean your setup with: `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get autoclean`. After that, reboot and try to install `k3b` again.

Comment: I think you have broken packages, incompleted apt-get update, or packages from PPA. I have written DVD-RW with k3b last week on Ubuntu 16.04.3. You could try `sudo apt-get autoremove; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt-get install k3b; sudo apt-get install -f; sudo apt-get upgrade -f`. Hope this helps.